# Unity Animation Event не срабатывает

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Анимация *Move* состоит из одного кадра и одного *Event*. В случае, если эта анимация начинается после *End*, игрок зависает в состоянии *Move*, но метод из *Event* не запускается, что блокирует движение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, где происходит зависание:

```
private IEnumerator PostMove()
{
    // ждём окончания движения
    while (animator.GetBool("isMove")) { yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate(); }
    // запускаем корутину обычного движения
    mainDirection = secondDirection; 

    animator.SetBool("isMove", true);
    secMovement = null;
    secondDirection = Direction.zero;
}
```

После переключения состояние в строке `animator.SetBool("isMove", true);` Происходит переключение на *Move*, но *Event* не срабатывает.

При добавлении `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();` перед `animator.SetBool("isMove", true);` всё работает лучше, но иногда всё также зависает.
Пробовал использовать State Machine Behaviours:

```
override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    animator.GetComponent<Player>().StartMove();
}
```

Но и тут аналогичная ситуация.

Почему в этом случае не срабатывает Event и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Глупая ошибка, но вдруг кому-то поможет. *Event* и подобные функции *Unity* не срабатывали из-за того, что *animator* и не выходил из своего состояния, несмотря на `animator.SetBool("isMove", false);` , ибо, видимо, в том же кадре оно возвращалось обратно, следуя указаниям скрипта управления, в моём случае.

Выяснил экспериментальным путём с помощью *State Machine Behaviours*.